# How to set default value for an optional list parameter in keyword

Tags: robotframework, optional-parameters, optional-arguments

I've previously used a list as parameter to take in a variable/optional number of arguments to a keyword, and this has worked perfectly:

```
Keyword Name
[Arguments]  ${otherVariable}  @{args}

....
```

My question is how do I set up a default value for this, if the user omits any more values?

i.e. something like

```
Keyword Name
[Arguments]  ${otherVariable}  @{args}=['0']

....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check is `${args}` empty, and if so - set the default value to it:

```
Keyword Name
    [Arguments]  ${otherVariable}  @{args}
    ${args}=    Run Keyword If    not $args    Create List    0
                             ...    ELSE       Set Variable   ${args}    # varags were passed, leave it as is
```

---

This is analogous to this python code (RF is based on it, so a lot of approaches / recipes are the same/pretty close):

```
def keword(otherVariable, *args):
    if not args: args = [0]
```